# Joypad-controllable full-screen application menu

Tags: windows-7, gaming

I'm searching Google for an application that will behave as a menu for a list of games for windows 7, that I can use on start-up with a joypad, so I don't need to touch the mouse to load a game. I've had a good hunt on Google and other than XBMC - which is way too much for what I want - didn't find anything what I want. Something basic like thumb image and title for each application will suffice.

I'm not looking to use a joypad/mouse emulator along with some other pc software if possible.

I'm trying to find out if there is a particular keyword to such applications that would aid me in my search, does this particular type of application have a name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Steam launched Big Picture mode, you can set it to start on boot and using a controller only.

A simple solution would be to create a new Steam account with nothing on it and start adding non-Steam games to your library. You can assign non-Steam games a thumb image and title outside of Big Picture mode, so your collection can look neat and organized.

Comment: Do I have to be online for it to work?